# Как узнать, кто использует класс?

Tags: java, классы

На низком уровне нужно определить имя класса, который его использует. Возможно ли это? Вижу решение в передаче имени в конструктор, но это мне не нравится. Упрощенный пример (в классе MyCommonClass нужно узнать имя класса, который его использует ):

```
package com.tasks5.extenden;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class MyApp {
    static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(MyApp.class.getName());
    public static void main(String args[]){
        MyCommonClass test = new MyCommonClass(MyApp.class.getName());
        log.info("test info maun class");
    }
}


package com.tasks5.extenden;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class MyCommonClass {
    static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    public MyCommonClass(String UsesClassName){
       log = LogManager.getLogger(UsesClassName);
   }

   public void Run(){
        log.info("info test");
   }
 }
```

Comment: зачем это нужно?

Comment: По поводу зачем это нужно. Пишу приложение-вертушку на сервер. Это приложение будет "крутить" несколько задач. Для каждой задачи - свой лог файл. Есть одни и те же классы, которые используются в разных задачах. И в этих "общих"  классах есть строки с информацией, которые должны быть записаны в нужный лог файл. Как-то так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю зачем вам это, но как вариант просто запрашивайте StackTrace для того, что бы узнать кто вас вызвал.

> Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()

Comment: StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = 
    Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    String message = "";
    if(stackTraceElements.length >= 3) {
        StackTraceElement element = stackTraceElements[2];
        String className = element.getClassName();
        String methodName = element.getMethodName();
        message = className + ": " + methodName;
    }

Answer (score 3):

То, что вы хотите сделать - плохо. Это нарушение как минимум трех принципов хорошего кода сразу: принципа малой связности, принципа единой ответственности и принципа минимальной информированности.

Если прямо вот вообще никак не избежать использования таких костылей, то не усложняйте себе жизнь - явно передавайте контекст в методы класса, которым он нужен (как самый наглядный пример - [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) в Android) или, в самом крайнем случае, в конструктор.

Answer (score 0):

Задача эта далеко не тривиальная. Если забыть о вопросе "зачем это нужно", то я бы посмотрел в сторону

> ClassLoader

Получить текущий можно например так:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
```

Далее, немного магии Reflection, и у вас будет

```
Vector<Class<?>> classes
```

по факту, это все загруженные классы.

Ну а далее, все более-менее просто - находите нужный вам класс и анализируете его (импорт, поля, возвращаемые значения методов).